# Graph visualization using prefuse is too dense

Tags: java, visualization, prefuse

The graph I have created using prefuse (shown below) is too dense! There are many nodes linking to many other nodes. Is there anyway I could display this more spread out?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using a force based layout? If so, change the force parameters of your layout, or try a different layout action (radial, fructherman-rheinhold, etc). Most of the prefuse layouts have flexible layout parameters, which should fix your problem.

In particular, use `ForceDirectedLayout.getForceSimulator()` to retrieve the ForceSimulator object for your layout, then change the parameters in your force array, which you can obtain via `ForceSimulator,getForces()`

The default forces for the default ForceSimulator behind a ForceDirectedLayout are organized as follows:

index0 is NBodyForce:

- Parameter 0 is gravitational force
- Parameter 1 is distance
- Parameter 2 is barnes-hut theta (a simulation quality parameter)

index1 is DragForce (param 0 is drag)

index 2 is Spring force (for
   edges)

- Parameter 0 is Spring Coefficient (how snappy the spring is)
- Parameter 1 is Spring (equilibrium) length

Comment: A related example is examined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30441734/230513).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest taking a look at [Gephi](http://gephi.org/). You get quite a lot of flexibility when it comes to layouts that should help.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you use [JUNG](http://jung.sourceforge.net/), even if it turns out to be dense, Jung gives an option for zoomin and zoom out which might give a work around for your problem.

Comment: -1 for given with little understanding of the problem and less understanding of prefuse.