# Prefuse graph manually set force parameters

Tags: java, graph-visualization, prefuse

Like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9713339/graph-visualization-using-prefuse-is-too-dense), my Prefuse graph is too dense to see anything. So I tried the approach suggested by @bcr in the accepted answer. However, it does not work for me. This is what I tried:

I retrieved the default settings. Then I changed the 2nd parameter of `NBodyForce` from `ForceSimulator` (called `Distance`) and the second parameter of `SpringForce` (called `DefaultSpringLength`) and fed them—along with the other default values—into my new `ForceSimulator`. But nothing in the output changed. What am I getting wrong?

This is my code:

```
private static void visualiseGraph(Graph graph) {
    Visualization vis = new Visualization();
    vis.add("graph", graph);
    LabelRenderer r = new LabelRenderer("someLabel");
    r.setRoundedCorner(8, 8);
    vis.setRendererFactory(new DefaultRendererFactory(r));
    ColorAction fill = new ColorAction("graph.nodes",
            VisualItem.FILLCOLOR, ColorLib.rgb(190,190,255));
    ColorAction text = new ColorAction("graph.nodes",
        VisualItem.TEXTCOLOR, ColorLib.gray(0));
    ColorAction edges = new ColorAction("graph.edges",
        VisualItem.STROKECOLOR, ColorLib.rgb(255,180,180)); 
    ActionList color = new ActionList();
    color.add(fill);
    color.add(text);
    color.add(edges);
    ActionList layout = new ActionList(Activity.INFINITY);
    Force[] originalForces = new ForceDirectedLayout("").getForceSimulator().getForces();
    ForceDirectedLayout fdl = new ForceDirectedLayout("graph"){
        @Override
        public ForceSimulator getForceSimulator() {
            ForceSimulator fs = new ForceSimulator();
            fs.addForce(new NBodyForce(originalForces[0].getParameter(0), 100, originalForces[0].getParameter(2)));
            fs.addForce(originalForces[1]);
            fs.addForce(new SpringForce(originalForces[2].getParameter(0), 100));
            return fs;
        }
    };
    layout.add(fdl);
    layout.add(new RepaintAction());
    vis.putAction("color", color);
    vis.putAction("layout", layout);
    Display display = new Display(vis) {
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(W, H);
        }
    };
    display.pan(W / 2, H / 2);
    display.addControlListener(new DragControl()); // drag items around
    display.addControlListener(new PanControl());  // pan with background left-drag
    display.addControlListener(new ZoomControl()); // zoom with vertical right-drag
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("prefuse example");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(display);
    frame.pack();           
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    vis.run("color");
    vis.run("layout");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach might be to add a `JForcePanel`, which is a

> Swing component for configuring the parameters of the `Force` functions in a given `ForceSimulator`. Useful for exploring different parameterizations when crafting a visualization.

This might help you to find the optimal parameters to use in your implementation of `getForceSimulator()`.

```
ForceSimulator fsim = ((ForceDirectedLayout) layout.get(0)).getForceSimulator();
JForcePanel fpanel = new JForcePanel(fsim);
frame.add(fpanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Among the `demos` included in the distribution, `prefuse.demos.GraphView` is a complete example. Empirically, it seems as though some parameters have more or less effect depending on the chosen data set.

**Addendum**: Looking closer, I see that your approach leaves the internal state of `fdl` unchanged. Instead, create a new `ForceSimulator` and use it in the layout and force panel; the example below changes the `defaultLength` of a `SpringForce` from `DEFAULT_SPRING_LENGTH` to `42`.

```
ForceDirectedLayout fdl = new ForceDirectedLayout("graph");
ForceSimulator fs = new ForceSimulator();
fs.addForce(new NBodyForce());
fs.addForce(new DragForce());
fs.addForce(new SpringForce(DEFAULT_SPRING_COEFF, 42));
fdl.setForceSimulator(fs);
```

Alternatively, update the `SpringForce` directly, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11675421/230513).

```
ForceDirectedLayout fdl = new ForceDirectedLayout("graph");
ForceSimulator fs = fdl.getForceSimulator();
Force[] forces = fs.getForces();
SpringForce sf = (SpringForce) forces[2];
sf.setParameter(SPRING_LENGTH, 42);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. The JForcePanel is very useful and a funny toy, while setting the forces' parameters in the way you did it worked perfectly.

Comment: a comment for those who may run into the same problems that I did: I had to do fs.addForce(new SpringForce(SpringForce.DEFAULT_SPRING_COEFF, <some_value>)); and the NBody and DragForces' constructors only accept floats, not doubles, which is the default in Java.

Comment: one more comment: you can use values from a broader range than the ones suggested by JForcePanel and they take effect.

Comment: @anjuta: Right; the slider limits are just the default min/max constants defined in each `Force` implementation.